# how to find first and last record from mysql table

Tags: mysql

I have one table I want to find first and last record that satisfy criteria of particular month.

Comment: multiple answers work, please select one

Answer (score 34):

```
SELECT 
(SELECT column FROM table WHERE [condition] ORDER BY column LIMIT 1) as 'first',
(SELECT column FROM table WHERE [condition] ORDER BY column DESC LIMIT 1) as 'last'
```

This worked for me when I needed to select first and the last date in the event series.

Answer (score 29):

First and last make sense only when you have the output of the query sorted on a field(s).

To get the first record:

```
select col1 from tab1 order by col1 asc limit 1;
```

To get the last record:

```
select col1 from tab1 order by col1 desc  limit 1;
```

Comment: Simple and concise. Thanks.

Comment: Isn't this only when the table is sorted according to some column. What if it is not at all sorted then how to do this?

Answer (score 15):

How about something like:

```
select 'first', f1, f2, f3, f4 from tbl
    order by f1 asc, f2 asc
    limit 1
union all
select 'last', f1, f2, f3, f4 from tbl
    order by f1 desc, f2 desc
    limit 1
```

Obviously feel free to add whatever condition you want in a `where` clause but the basic premise of the `order by` is to reverse the order in the two `select` sections.

The `limit` clause will just get the first row in both cases. That just happens to be the *last* row of set in the second `select` due to the fact that you've reversed the ordering.

If there is only one row resulting from your conditions and you don't want it returned twice, use `union` instead of `union all`.

Comment: What about parentheses?

Comment: @Alexander, yes parentheses are very nice, and have a smooth flow about them. They're also very attractive if they're balanced correctly. However, they're not really necessary for my answer to work so I'll leave them out of the equation for now :-)

Comment: Without parentheses I'm getting an exception `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1221 Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY`

Comment: I don't know if that had worked in any version prior to 5.5. But at least since 5.5 you need parentheses. This is documented for [5.5](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/union.html) as well as for [8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html): "*To apply `ORDER BY` or `LIMIT` to an individual `SELECT`, place the clause inside the parentheses that enclose the `SELECT`*". Also `UNION (DISTINCT)` will not change anything, since `first` and `last` are already distinct.

Answer (score 10):

```
select * from table
where id = (select id from tab1 order by col1 asc limit 1) or
id = (select id from tab1 order by col1 desc  limit 1);
```

Comment: The semi colons in your subqueries will break this statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one: take for example you want to group your table based on group_col and get the first and last value of value_col:

```
select substring_index(group_concat(value_col), ',',1) as 'first',
        substring_index(group_concat(value_col), ',',-1) as 'last' 
from table
group by group_col
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT first_name, LENGTH(first_name) FROM Employees
    ORDER BY LENGTH(first_name) ASC
    FETCH FIRST 1 rows ONLY)
UNION
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT first_name, LENGTH(first_name) FROM Employees
    ORDER BY LENGTH(first_name) DESC
    FETCH FIRST 1 rows ONLY)
ORDER BY 2 desc;
```

Comment: `FETCH FIRST` is not valid MySQL syntax

Comment: @FrankerZ: Thanks for pointing. Yeah, the FETCH FIRST is for Oracle Sql.