# Get the first and last record of each item for the month

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Product ID     Quantity     DateAdded
1              100          4/1/14
2              200          4/2/14
3              300          4/2/14
1              80           4/3/14
3              40           4/5/14
2              5            4/6/14
1              10           4/7/14
```

I am using this SQL statement to display the first and last record of each item:

```
SELECT 
    ProductID, MIN(Quantity) AS Starting, MAX(Quantity) AS Ending 
FROM 
    Records
WHERE 
    DateAdded BETWEEN '2014-04-01' AND '2014-04-30'
GROUP BY 
    ProductID, Quantity
```

but I am getting the same values for the Starting and Ending columns. I want to achieve something like this:

```
Product ID     Starting     Ending
1              100          10
2              200          5
3              300          40
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2735423/3531180
Is this something you are looking for?

Comment: might the date declaration '4/6/14' be declared as 'd/m/yy'? if so, you only have 1 record of that month in the database so min and max is equal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the same quantities because you are aggregating by `quantity` in the `group by` as well as product.  Your version of the query, properly written would be:

```
SELECT ProductID, MIN(Quantity) AS Starting, MAX(Quantity) AS Ending 
FROM Records
WHERE DateAdded BETWEEN '2014-04-01' AND '2014-04-30'
GROUP BY ProductID;
```

However, this doesn't give you the first and last values.  It only gives you the minimum and maximum ones.  To get those values, use `row_number()` and conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT ProductID,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum_asc = 1 THEN Quantity END) as Starting,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum_desc = 1 THEN Quantity END) as Ending
FROM (SELECT r.*,
             row_number() over (partition by product order by dateadded asc) as seqnum_asc,
             row_number() over (partition by product order by dateadded desc) as seqnum_desc
      FROM Records r
     ) r
WHERE DateAdded BETWEEN '2014-04-01' AND '2014-04-30'
GROUP BY ProductID;
```

If you are using SQL Server 2012, then you can also use this with `FIRST_VALUE()` and `LAST_VALUE()` instead of `row_number()`.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `row_number()` ranking function

```
select starting.*, ending.ending
from
    (select ProductID, quantity as starting from 
            (select * , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by productid order by dateadded) rn 
             from yourtable   
             where DateAdded BETWEEN '2014-04-01' AND '2014-04-30'
     ) first 
     where rn = 1) starting
    inner join 
    (select ProductID, quantity as ending from 
            (select * , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by productid order by dateadded desc) rn 
             from yourtable   
             where DateAdded BETWEEN '2014-04-01' AND '2014-04-30'
    ) last 
    where rn = 1) ending
    on starting.productid=ending.productid
```

The first subquery gets the first entry for the time period, the second gets the last entry

Comment: This seems more like a decent answer compared to the other 2, which I don't get how they get 2 upvote each?

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to this

```
SELECT 
    ProductID, MIN(Quantity) AS Starting, MAX(Quantity) AS Ending 
FROM 
    Records
WHERE 
    DateAdded BETWEEN '2014-04-01' AND '2014-04-30'
GROUP BY 
    ProductID
```

you don't need to make a group for quantity

Comment: I don't think he wants to get the min and maximum, seems more like he wants to get by the earliest and latest date.

Comment: I think he is mentioned his problem as `but I am getting the same values for the Starting and Ending columns. I want to achieve something like this:`

Comment: Yes, you will get the same result but this is not the logic he wants. It's just on pure luck that it's also the minimum and maximum value for that particular month, but if the data is changed for future months and the latest date is not the minimum / maximum, your logic and result will be totally wrong.

Comment: I don't think `min` will ever return 100 and `max` return 10 for the same product no matter what the data.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @test Table 
(ID INT, Name INT)
INSERT INTO @test 
VALUES
(1,  100),
(2, 200),
(3,  300 ),
(1,  5),
(2, 10),
    (3, 15);

    select ID,MIN(name),MAX(name) from @test
    group by ID
```

Comment: I don't think he wants to get the min and maximum, seems more like he wants to get by the earliest and latest date.

Answer (score 0):

This works in 2012 and newer:

```
with x as (
select distinct productid
,first_value(quantity) over(partition by productid order by dateadded
    range between unbounded preceding  and current row) as starting
,last_value(quantity) over(partition by productid order by dateadded
    range between current row and unbounded following) as ending
from #t
)
select productid, starting, ending
from x
```

Single pass through the table.

Answer (score -1):

I did not try it on SQL Server but on MySQL this SQL is working:

```
SELECT 
    ProductID, MAX(Quantity) AS Starting, MIN(Quantity) AS Ending 
FROM 
    Records
WHERE 
    DateAdded BETWEEN '2014-04-01' AND '2014-04-30'
GROUP BY 
    ProductID;
```

For DateAdded field:

```
SELECT 
    ProductID, MAX(Quantity) AS Starting, MIN(Quantity) AS Ending 
FROM 
    Records
WHERE 
    convert(datetime, DateAdded) BETWEEN '2014-04-01' AND '2014-04-30'
GROUP BY 
    ProductID;
```

P.S. Missing sqlfiddle badly.. :(