# How to find a last record for a record in first table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a first table of users which have a boolean field to represent a user as `active` and in the second table i have user `audits`.

I have to find when a user is activated last time, so that means i have many number of `audits` just have to get last activated `audit` for a currently `active` user.

> Fields of User Table:

```
user_id, username, firstname, lastname, email, isactive
```

> Fields of Audit Table:

```
user_id, audit_date, actiontype
```

Comment: "which have a boolean field to represent a user as active "  I coudnt find this bool en field in your table definition

Comment: @MaheshMadushanka  Sorry forget to mention that, just added that field now.

Comment: you want to get only the max(audit_date)  ? or else do you want to get actiontype and date

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to find first and last record from mysql table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735395/how-to-find-first-and-last-record-from-mysql-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess You want this:

```
SELECT 
  user_table.*, MAX(audit_table.audit_date) AS last_activated
FROM audit_table 
LEFT JOIN user_table ON (user_table.user_id = audit_table.user_id) 
WHERE 
  audit_table.user_id = 5 AND audit_table.actiontype = 'activate' 
  AND user_table.isactive = 1;
```

If You want list of activated users with last activation date:

```
SELECT 
  user_table.*, MAX(audit_table.audit_date) AS last_activated 
FROM audit_table 
LEFT JOIN user_table ON (user_table.user_id = audit_table.user_id) 
WHERE 
  audit_table.actiontype = 'activate' AND user_table.isactive = 1
GROUP BY audit_table.user_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a temp table with max audti_date

```
select * from user 
INNER  JOIN  (select user_id, max(audit_date) 
             from AUDIT group by user_id) a on a.user_id = USER.user_id 
where user.isactive = true
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the most recent date using aggregation:

```
select user_id, max(audit_date) as maxad
from user_audits
where isactive = 1
group by user_id;
```

You can get all the information from the audit table by joining it to the above information:

```
select au.*
from user_audits au join
     (select user_id, max(audit_date) as maxad
      from user_audits
      where isactive = 1
      group by user_id
     ) u
     on au.user_id = u.user_id and au.audit_date = u.maxad and au.isactive = 1
```