# Capturing Both First and Last Rows in Query into PHP Variables

Tags: php

I'm echoing out all the rows on a page for a query of mine.

I also need to capture the first row and last row into PHP variables to do a calculation.

```
db = new mysqli('server','username','password','database'); 

$resource = $db->query("SELECT . . . (my query, not wanting to modify this)");
```

I can get the last row into a variable like this.

```
$numResults  = $resource->num_rows;
$counter = 0;
while ( $rows = $resource->fetch_assoc() ) {
if (++$counter == $numResults) {
$lastrow = $rows['column'];
}
```

I can get the first row in a php variable like this.

```
$first = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resource);
$firstrow = $first['column'];
```

But it seems it is only allowing me to do one or the other.

If I comment out the first block of code to get `$lastrow`, my second block to get `$firstrow` shows up.
If I comment out the second block of code to get `$firstrow`, my first block to get `$lastrow` shows up.

Anyone know of any tricks I can use so that I can get both `$firstrow` and `$lastrow` into variables on the same page using PHP?

Comment: Not sure why you don't want to amend the query, i would have two queries, one for each record. have a look at [how-to-find-first-and-last-record-from-mysql-table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735395/how-to-find-first-and-last-record-from-mysql-table), this also would avoid fetching all the unnecessary records in between

Comment: My thinking is parsing it in PHP would be better than having multiple queries.  Also there are no unnecessary records in between.  As I said I am echoing out every single row on my page, but only need to capture the first row and last row as variables.

Comment: ah, sorry I missed the point that you are using all the records anyway. then you are in the right track :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do it. Below are 2 of them.

1) Similar to your example - this is simple to understand as it uses a while loop and an if structure

```
$firstRow = $resource->fetch_assoc();
$lastRow = NULL;
while ( $rows = $resource->fetch_assoc() ) {
    $lastRow = $rows;
}
if(!isset($lastRow)) $lastRow = $firstRow;
```

2) Using mysqli_data_seek - http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php

```
// First Row
$resource->data_seek(0);
$firstRow = $resource->fetch_assoc();
// Last Row
$resource->data_seek($resource->num_rows - 1);
$lastRow = $resource->fetch_assoc();
```

Comment: Perfect! That is it.  Tried both of them and they both returned the first and last rows as arrays. `mysqli_data_seek` especially looks incredibly simple and seems to work well, wasn't aware of that function.

Answer (score 1):

If your above code is working then try following

```
$numResults  = $resource->num_rows;
$counter = 0;
while ( $rows = $resource->fetch_assoc() ) {

   if ($counter == 0) {
       $firstrow = $rows['column'];
   } 

   if (++$counter == $numResults) {
      $lastrow = $rows['column'];
   }

}
```

Comment: Yes I tried that, didn't think to mention it because I didn't think it was proper.  Just tried it again and `$firstrow` is only echoing out the first character in the row.  To be more specific `$firstrow` is only echoing out `9` when it should be `985`

Comment: I don't understand, why this is happening. It will be help-full to understand if you describe your table structure and your query also.

Comment: I am not sure either. I've had this happen before (results only returning first letter of variable).. I'll have to search around to figure out why it does this sometimes.  Either way, it looks like `mysqli_data_seek` was what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple ... Rows are like arrays !!!

As you got your number of rows in `$numResults` ...

For first row -- `$rows[0]`
For last row -- `$rows[$numresults-1]`

Totally try below ..

```
$numResults  = $resource->num_rows;
$firstrow = $rows[0]; //first
$rows[$numresults-1]; //last
```

Hope this helps ...

Comment: Sorry perhaps I am not understanding it.  `$numResults  = $resource->num_rows;
$counter = 0;
while ( $rows = $resource->fetch_assoc() ) {
$firstrow = $rows[0];
$lastrow = $rows[$numResults-1];
}
print_r($firstrow);
print_r($lastrow);` is not returning anything.  I also tried it without the while loop just `$rows = $resource->fetch_assoc();` to declare `$rows` ..

Comment: echo out $numResults. Are you getting the correct number of rows in your table that match your query??

Comment: Yes I tested out $numResults and it is returning the correct number. I am not sure why your method is not working. It is not capturing any variables, just blank