# How can i get the 1st in and last out without all the middle value on the same day

Tags: mysql

My query is:

```
SELECT id, employee_number, MAX(time_in_out)
FROM raw_attendance
GROUP BY id
```

and the result is:

[image: Result]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735395/how-to-find-first-and-last-record-from-mysql-table try this

Comment: What is your expected result?  You never showed us that (or if you did, then you never showed your current result).

Comment: Sorry, i want to get the 1st time in and the last out without the middle seen on the picture that i've uploaded

Comment: No pictures thanks. Instead, and if you're still struggling with this, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT
id,
  employee_number,
 date(ra.time_in_out) as as_of_date,
      (SELECT
          time_in_out
        FROM raw_attendance rmax
        WHERE (rmax.time_in_out)= (ra.time_in_out)
        ORDER BY time_in_out DESC LIMIT 1) AS max_time,
      (SELECT
          time_in_out
        FROM raw_attendance rmin
        WHERE (rmin.time_in_out)=(ra.time_in_out)
        ORDER BY time_in_out ASC LIMIT 1) AS min_time

FROM raw_attendance ra
GROUP BY date(ra.time_in_out)
```

Comment: sorry, my question in not clear i want to get 1st time in and last time out on the same day

Comment: @JaeBasagre I edited the answer to return the entire table by id and day, assuming you don’t want to look at one day at a time. Forgive the formatting, I updated on my phone.

Comment: Don't use GROUP BY in non-aggregating queries. It just confuses everybody

Comment: @Strawberry how is this not aggregated? OP wants min/max per day. Look at the screenshot, what would be the point of returning all of those time stamps?

Comment: It's not aggregated because you use no aggregating functions. I don't do screenshots

Comment: not sure what to tell you then, this concisely solves OPs problem, I’m sorry it confuses you due to your inability to read text on a picture.